# Ways to find a practice area

Tags: flight-training, checkride

I am taking a check-ride at an unfamiliar airport.  How should I look for a practice area for maneuvers?

Comment: Ask a local. You really should familiarize yourself with the area before your check ride. It's stressful enough without adding unfamiliarity to the mix.

Comment: If you're doing a checkride (one assumes with an instructor) won't they show you the practice area(s) they typically use?